# Selecting and updating against tables in separate data sources within the same transaction

Tags: spring-integration

The attributes for the `<jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>` component in Spring Integration include `data-source`, `sql` and `update`. These allow for separate SELECT and UPDATE statements to be run against tables in the specified database. Both sql statements will be part of the same transaction.

The limitation here is that both the SELECT and UPDATE will be performed against the same data source. Is there a workaround for the case when the the UPDATE will be on a table in  a different data source (not just separate databases on the same server)?

Our specific requirement is to select rows in a table which have a timestamp prior to a specific time. That time is stored in a table in a  separate data source. (It could also be stored in a file). If both sql statements used the same database, the `<jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>` would work well for us out of the box. In that case, the SELECT could use the time stored, say, in table A as part of the WHERE clause in the query run against table B. The time in table A would then be updated to the current time, and all this would be part of one transaction.

One idea I had was, within the `sql` and `update` attributes of the adapter, to use SpEL to call methods in a bean. The method defined for `sql` would look up a time stored in a file, and then return the full SELECT statement. The method defined for `update` would update the time in the same file and return an empty string. However, I don't think such an approach is failsafe, because the reading and writing of the file would not be part of the same transaction that the data source is using.

If, however, the `update` was guaranteed to only fire upon commit of the data source transaction, that would work for us. If the event of a failure, the database transaction would commit, but the file would not be updated. We would then get duplicate rows, but should be able to handle that. The issue would be if the file was updated and the database transaction failed. That would mean lost messages, which we could not handle.

If anyone has any insights as to how to approach this scenario it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use two different channel adapters with a pub-sub channel, or an outbound gateway followed by an outbound channel adapter.

If necessary, start the transaction(s) upstream of both; if you want true atomicity you would need to use an XA transaction manager and XA datasources. Or, you can get close by synchronizing the two transactions so they get committed very close together.

See [Dave Syer's article "Distributed transactions in Spring, with and without XA"](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html) and specifically the section on Best Efforts 1PC.

Comment: Thanks. I think the question can be simplified: what is the best way, in Spring Integration, to ensure that a piece of code executes AFTER a transaction completes?

Comment: See http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/transactions.html#transaction-synchronization - add transaction synchronization to the poller and put some flow after the "after-commit" channel.

Comment: That works, but the problem is that when the poller returns an empty result set, the service-adapter attached to the after-commit channel is not called. That means that the timestamp being used in the SELECT statement will not be updated. The same empty result set will then continue to be read. The logs show: "SourcePollingChannelAdapter - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'. Initiating transaction commit". So even though the transaction gets commited, the fact that the poller returns false appears to break the Transaction Synchronization mechanism. Is there a workaround?

Comment: I wouldn't say it "breaks" the mechanism - it is intended so you can take some action after some real work was done (or failed). Since there's no data from the poll, there's no message to "post process". One work around might be to subclass `JdbcTemplate` and override `<T> T query(String sql, SqlParameterSource paramSource, ResultSetExtractor<T> rse) throws DataAccessException;` (which is the method called by the adapter). You can delegate to `super` and detect an empty list and take some action. Inject an instance of the custom template into the adapter using the `jdbc-operations` attribute.